# Replacement battery voltage mismatch tolerance?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I want to try replacing a proprietary battery in an electronic of mine as a first electronics DIY project.
Thing is, the stock battery is 3.6V, and the phone battery I have on hand that I would like to use is 3.8V. The replacement battery also has a charge voltage of 4.35V, and the AC adapter for the electronic is 5V. I've tried looking up if this will be a problem, but everything I've read is written waaayyyy beyond my skill level.

Are either a .2V difference in the batteries or a .65V difference between the battery and AC adapter significant differences that makes this build unsafe?

Also, is 24awg wire sufficient for wiring everything up? I would be soldering the replacement battery to the pcb inside of the proprietary battery.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for asking such basic questions.

Comment: 3.6V is a pretty standard voltage for lithium ions -  I suggest, if you want to be safe, that you just buy a replacement battery, or if possible, a similar one that you can put in. The outer casing for the battery could well be proprietary, but if you can fit a 18650 or something in there, it might also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the battery you want to use is a typical lithium ion battery then what you want to do could be very dangerous.

Rechargeable lithium batteries require carefully designed charging circuits to prevent them from being overcharged with too much current or a voltage that is too high. A difference in charging voltage of 0.65 V could destroy the battery or cause it to catch fire.

Whether or not a battery with a voltage higher than 3.6 V would damage your device is impossible to say without a detailed knowledge of the device itself. Someone could guess, or give you an opinion, but we can't give you a definite answer based on the information you have provided.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I knew there was probably something fishy about the battery I wanted to use. The replacement battery is coming out of a phone, so I'm sure it's capable of doing that stuff, but AFAIK there's no way to interface the hardware that prevents that stuff with the device I'm using. Thanks again.